# Simple PHP Authentication Looping

Tags: php, html, session, authentication, web

Hi: I'm trying to implement authentication on a PHP web page using $_SESSION; however, it is looping me back to the authentication page. Anybody know why? Code I am using is below:

On the page requiring authentication:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['authenticated']) || $_SESSION['authenticated'] != 'true') {
    header('Location: duo.php');
}
?>
```

The login/authentication page:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('duo_web.php');
echo "<center><h2>This site requires authentication.</h2>";
echo "<br><hr>";
unset($_SESSION['authenticated']);
if(isset($_POST['sig_response'])){
        $resp = Duo::verifyResponse(get_cfg_var('duo_ikey'), get_cfg_var('duo_skey'), get_cfg_var('duo_akey'), $_POST['sig_response']);
        if($resp != NULL){
                $_SESSION['authenticated'] = 'true'; header('Location: index.php');
        }
}
else if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
        if($_POST['user'] == get_cfg_var('duo_user') && $_POST['pass'] == get_cfg_var('duo_pass')) {
                $sig_request = Duo::signRequest(get_cfg_var('duo_ikey'), get_cfg_var('duo_skey'), get_cfg_var('duo_akey'), $_POST['user']);
?>
                <script src="Duo-Web-v1.bundled.min.js"></script>
                <input type="hidden" id="duo_host" value="<?php echo get_cfg_var('duo_host') ; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="duo_sig_request" value="<?php echo $sig_request; ?>">
                <script src="Duo-Init.js"></script>
                <iframe id="duo_iframe" width="620" height="500" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="background: transparent;"></iframe>
<?php
        }
}
else {
        echo "<form action='duo.php' method='post'>";
        echo "Username: <input type='text' name='user' /> <br />";
        echo "Password: <input type='password' name='pass' /> <br />";
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit' />";
        echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

EDIT: I tried moving my actual content to a back.index.php and putting only the above code in it and I am still getting the loop, so the issue has to be in my login (duo.php) page. I have added all of the code from the page above.

Answer (score 1):

On the page requiring authentication, session_start() needs to be after the opening php tag.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['authenticated']) || $_SESSION['authenticated'] != 'true') {
    header('Location: duo.php');
}
```

Comment: It is; a typo on my part when I was adding the code tags. Corrected in question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi: So this is what worked for me. The issue was in the variable not being saved to $_SESSION. I had to move it to a different location in the page and I replaced ' with ":

On the page requiring authorization:

```
<?php
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", "0");
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", "3600");
session_start();
$var = $_SESSION["authenticated"];
if(strcmp($var,'yes') !== 0){
        header('Location: duo.php');
}
?>
```

On the login page:

```
<?php
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", "0");
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", "3600");
session_start();
include('duo_web.php');
echo "<center><h2>This site requires authentication.</h2>";
echo "<br><hr>";
if(isset($_POST['sig_response'])){
        $resp = Duo::verifyResponse(get_cfg_var('duo_ikey'), get_cfg_var('duo_skey'), get_cfg_var('duo_akey'), $_POST['sig_response']);
        if($resp != NULL){
                header('Location: index.php');
        }
}
else if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
        if($_POST['user'] == get_cfg_var('duo_user') && $_POST['pass'] == get_cfg_var('duo_pass')) {
                $sig_request = Duo::signRequest(get_cfg_var('duo_ikey'), get_cfg_var('duo_skey'), get_cfg_var('duo_akey'), $_POST['user']);
?>
                <script src="Duo-Web-v1.bundled.min.js"></script>
                <input type="hidden" id="duo_host" value="<?php echo get_cfg_var('duo_host') ; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="duo_sig_request" value="<?php $_SESSION["authenticated"] = "yes"; echo $sig_request; ?>">
                <script src="Duo-Init.js"></script>
                <iframe id="duo_iframe" width="620" height="500" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="background: transparent;"></iframe>
<?php
        }
}
else {
        echo "<form action='duo.php' method='post'>";
        echo "Username: <input type='text' name='user' /> <br />";
        echo "Password: <input type='password' name='pass' /> <br />";
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit' />";
        echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

Hope this helps somebody else.